# Proof that when $R ∪ S$ is an equivalence relation then it is equal to $R ∘S$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $R$ and $S$ be equivalence relations on the same set.

I have to prove that when $R ∪ S$ is an equivalence relation, then $R∘S=R∪S$.

I know that I will have to use the definitions of composition and union to achieve this but I have no clue how I can show that those are the same.

And I know that $R ∪ S = R \lor S$ otherwise the union couldn't be transitive.

$R∪S=(x, y)\in R\lor(x, y)\in S$

$R$ ∘ $S$ $=$ $\{(x,z)\in X\times Z\mid \exists y\in Y:(x,y)\in S\land (y,z)\in R\}$.

Comment: When you can't figure out what going on, it ofter helps to make  a small example.  Take $R$ to be some arbitrary subset of $X\times X$ with $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\},$ say.  Take $S$ to be the smallest subset of $X\times X$ such that $R\cup S$ is an equivalence relation.  Is $R\circ S= R\cup S?$  Can you figure out why this would be true in general?  I haven't done the problem; this is how I would attack it.

Comment: $R=X\times X, S=\emptyset$ is a counterexample, since $R\circ\emptyset = \emptyset$  At the very least, we must assume, $R,S\neq \emptyset$

Comment: Don't $R$ and $S$ have to be equivalence relations on the same set?  I feel sure I can produce a counterexample if they're equivalence relations on different sets.

Comment: Yes I added this. @saulspatz
They have to be equivalent classes on the same set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $(x, z)\in R\circ S$. Then there is $y$ such that $(x, y)\in S$ and $(y, z)\in R$. So $(x, y), (y, z)\in R\cup S$ which implies $(x, z)\in R\cup S$ because $R\cup S$ is an equivalence relation.

If you assume that $R$ and $S$ are also equivalence relations, suppose $(x, z)\in R\cup S$. In particular let $(x, z)\in S$. Then $(z, z)\in R$ and which implies $(x, z)\in R\circ S$ as well. Similar case if $(x, z)\in R$.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!!
While I understand the proof I'm not sure if I could do it on my own. Have you got any hint how to approach this?

Comment: In this case  ''follow the definition'' approach worked out well i.e. start from the given hypotheses, see what they mean and some of its simple implications and work out the conclusions.